# possible to use a monitoring computer remotely and disconnect from it without closing the login screen?

Tags: remote, remote-desktop-services, remote-access

I have one Computer which is just running one application to monitor our server data. This Computer will only be used for this purpose and I will if there is a manageable possible solution unplug mouse and keyboard.

The monitoring tool is a web application so I just need to have firefox opened.

When I now connect remotely with Remote desktop control I can open the tool, but as soon as I connect I see the login screen on the monitoring screen...( I use the same account as i use on my computer to connect AD Account, tried another one, but it will log off the other user as well)

So what I need is to connect to that computer, start a tool and keep this window open. If it's only possible with having any other plugin installed, it's fine as well.
If you miss any neccessary information, let me know.

**EDIT : This is an additional monitoring system which does only run when i am in the office, i start it in the morning and i shut it off in the evening.**

Comment: 1) It's sad that nowadays software that needs to run continuously can't figure out that it should be a service.  2) I don't get your question to be honest.  It sounds like there's a timeout on the monitoring app?  If you remote in and run the app and then disconnect the session (RDP x button) everything in that session should continue to run.

Comment: A monitoring application with no notion of persistence? Is this a view over time (graph) or just a realtime view monitoring solution? Either way... running a server dedicated to running a web browser seems wrong and bad and awful.

Comment: thats just an additional monitoring system. to display the actual ram usage of services and disk space remaining etc. There is no timeout on the app. When i for example start the app on that computer and keep it displayed its fine. but i want to start it remotely without touching the computer, besides turning it on. When i start the app remotely, i only see the login screen instead of the app.  I need a way to connect remotely, start the app and then display the graphs and widgets AND NOT THE LOGIN SCREEN.  sorry i am no native english speaker :)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why not RDP to this machine, start the monitoring program, then minimize the RDP client window. What's difficult?

Comment: It sounds like this is not the actual monitoring system just a display for the monitoring system.  Like a digital signage kind of setup.

Answer (score 1):

Remote desktop will log the real display so you cant see it.

VNC on the other hand connects to the console session and leaves it open.  So install TightVNC or similar and connect with that.

I use this method on wall mounted video display systems and it works perfectly.

Comment: sounds exactly what i was looking for. Thanks, I'll try it on monday.